# Where does the "Frog's Theme" appear in Chrono Trigger?

Tags: chrono-trigger

I'm supposed to learn how to play the [Frog's Theme](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMzkUriqXvs) song from Chrono Trigger on SNES for a band I just joined. After thinking I knew how to play several other songs correctly, I found that by using an SNES emulator and silencing different sound channels there are frequently parts of the music that are buried in the mix. I want to learn the song right and make sure I don't miss anything, so I'm trying to get to the part in the game where the song appears so I can listen carefully to each "track" in the song. The problem is, I'm not very familiar with the game and don't know where the song appears.

I found some save states here:

- http://www.fantasyanime.com/squaresoft/ctsaves-srm.htm
- http://www.fantasyanime.com/squaresoft/ctsaves-enhasa.htm

I'm sure it's an awesome game but I don't have the time to play it all the way through just to look for this song. Could anyone tell me how I can quickly find it? Which save state should I start with, and then what do I need to do?

Comment: Is there an .spc player that lets you disable the tracks?  This would eliminate the need to do it in-emulator (and let you play tracks on demand).

Comment: Aha, .spc player... interesting. I'll have to take a look at that, I bet you can disable channels. I've never even heard of that, sound like the way to go. I'll check it out tonight after I'm done working, thanks for the info Shinrai. I hope there's a simple way to simply extract all the music without rom hacking knowledge (which I do not have currently), I would pay for something like that. Right now I'm recording my PC output with Audacity and saving as separate wavs (yeah, pretty ghetto).

Comment: Most emulators allow you to dump spc, but you should be able to find pretty much anything you want already online.  Here's the Chrono Trigger soundtrack: http://snesmusic.org/v2/profile.php?profile=set&selected=554

Comment: Once you "learn the song right", there are some excellent remixes of this theme on OverClocked ReMix: https://ocremix.org/song/56/frogs-theme

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A simple way to hear any character's theme (assuming that they have joined your group yet) is to not have them in the party, talk to them at The End of Time and tell them you want to change your party**, except when you're at the point where their sidequests are available. Regardless of whether you actually change your party or not, that character's theme will begin playing.

I recommend playing the entire game when you can as it is great but, for your purposes, it would be easiest to use one of the latter game saves, head to the end of time (remove Frog from the party if he's with you) and talk to Frog, telling him you want him in the party. Frog permanently joins the group when you hand him the Masamune and from then, except for brief points when you're in inescapable dungeons, you can pretty much go to The End of Time at your leisure either via time gates or using the epoch.

In the first list, the most convenient would be save state #14 slot 2 as the epoch is right nearby and you have completed Frog's quest.

Note that this is [the regular version of the song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBmX4RRBzvo) as is played throughout the entirety of the game. The version found in the OST and the linked youtube video does not appear to be in the game. I checked every narrative scene that featured Frog during the game and every ending and all of them that played Frog's Theme played the same looped/abbreviated version, not the one featured in the OST. I even checked the Playstation and DS remakes and neither version featured the OST version, not even in their music box sound test sort of deal. They all play the abbreviated version covered in the OST version in the youtube video from 0:16-0:46 and then loop.

If you're looking to separate out the voices in the full version featured in the OST (meaning the first 16 seconds), I'm afraid you're going to need to brush up on your listening skills or seek out further resources. I'm not sure if it will be helpful, but I came across a musical score for this version of the song [here](http://ichigos.com/res/getfile.php?id=1525&type=pdf&token=e327b1649d06bf74fceb4fe73f83bdba), but I'm not sure of the tempo/time signature as [the midi version they link](http://ichigos.com/res/getfile.php?id=1525&type=midi&token=e327b1649d06bf74fceb4fe73f83bdba) doesn't fit the exact same timing although the melody sounds correct as near as I can tell.

Comment: That's how I would have handled it too.

Comment: I ended up figuring out how to open the SPC file, but this is a great answer - thanks so much. Yeah I noticed the intro wasn't there, but since I was able to clearly hear each channel for the rest of the song I can figure it out easily now. Thanks a lot. I'll definitely have to play this through all the way some day.

Answer (score 5):

Frog's Theme shows up the first time you meet Frog, near the beginning of the game.  Following the first link you posted, if you use game save #1, slot #2, you should be right at the point where you meet Frog.  My memory is a bit hazy, so it may be slightly before or after that-- once you've loaded the state, check to make sure Frog isn't already with you; if so, load an earlier one.

That being said, you can just search his theme on Youtube and find it no problem.  Any particular reason you need to find it in the game?

Comment: The reason I need to find it in the game is clearly stated in my post, but thanks - I'll try your instructions. I do remember playing this a while ago and meeting Frog early in the game, I just wasn't sure that the song appeared at that point.

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry, I read your post but I guess I glossed over that particular phrase.  But yes, his song does show up the first time you meet him, I remember being awed by its/Frog's awesomeness the first time I played.

Comment: Well I just beat the Nun/Nagas in the Cathedral and got Frog, but still haven't heard the song. Any idea? Should it be coming up soon?

Comment: Are we talking about the same song? Did I miss it somehow?

Comment: Hmm. To be honest, I'm not positive.  I could have sworn that it showed up very soon after first meeting him. If you have the time, play through to the end of the 600AD segment you're currently in.  Frog should leave at some point (once you've reached Guardia castle), so if you haven't heard the theme by then you won't until you've met Frog again. Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: I do think we're talking about the same theme.  I should note that in the game, the theme starts at a different point in the song than it does in official recordings of the theme; but it's still very recognizable, I can't imagine that you missed it.

Comment: According to GameFAQs, he leaves your party at least twice after he first joins. I guess I'll have to keep playing or wait until someone else can help.

Comment: Normally, the theme to Frog plays a little after the fight with the Nagas : get back to the castle and Frog will leave your group. IIRC, his theme plays while he commends Cronos for his spirit right before splitting.

Comment: This answer is unfortunately incorrect. The theme that plays when you first meet frog is [Fanfare 1 ~ Lucca's Theme](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2nSEZ6kEuk). The first time you hear Frog's Theme is actually after you return to the castle after defeating Yakra and saving queen Leene - there's a bit of chatter, then Frog says he must go (cue Frog's Theme).